# 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'disabled' of undefined turn.js:1798 'error while integrating turn js with angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, turnjs

I am trying to implement page flipping effect with turn.js in my angular application. I am encountering the following error when i try navigating to some other view in the application.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'disabled' of undefined turn.js:1798
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opts' of undefined turn.js:1297

I am using a directive to invoke turn js. I tried unbinding turn from dom with $("#id").unbind(). But still it is not working. Do any one have an idea on this?

Comment: As a non-psychic, I can only tell you thah you're calling those two object properties, but the (each?) object itself is undefined.

Comment: I am not calling the objects anywhere else. I am getting this error after i navigate away from the view.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could replicate the problem on jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm getting a similar problem with `opts` being undefined. It's due to line 123 in the paid version of the plugin somewhere.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Try using the 4th release. It worked for me after I upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that the `opts` being undefined is merely from loading turn.js on a page that doesn't have anything to instantiate the plugin on.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue.